# [React-testing-library][FireEvent] Screen doesn't update after firing click event

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I'm trying to simulate the 'see more' functionality to a blog.

It works as expected on the browser but when I simulate the behavior on react testing library it doesn't.

```
describe('when 12 blogs', () => {
  describe('fetch more blogs', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      const twelveBlogs = generateBlogs(12);
      const twoBlogs = generateBlogs(10);
      Api.query.mockReturnValueOnce(twelveBlogs);
      Api.query.mockReturnValueOnce(twoBlogs);
    });
    test('should fetch more blog posts when clicking on "See More" button', async () => {
      render(
        <MemoryRouter>
          <Blog />
        </MemoryRouter>
      );
      const seeMoreButton = await screen.findByRole('button', {
        name: /See More/i,
      });

      fireEvent.click(seeMoreButton);

      await waitFor(() => expect(Api.query).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2));
      await waitFor(
        () =>
          expect(screen.getAllByText(/NaN de undefined de NaN/)).toHaveLength(
            15
          )
      );
    });
  });
});
```

And the implementation

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Api from '../../api/api';
import BlogPreview from '../../components/BlogPreview/BlogPreview';
import './Blog.css';

function Blog() {
  const [blogPosts, setBlogPosts] = useState([]);
  const pageSize = 12;
  const category = ['document.type', 'blog'];
  const orderings = '[my.blog.data desc]';
  const [apiPage, setApiPage] = useState(1);
  const [shouldFetchMoreBlogs, setShouldFetchMoreBlogs] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchApi(options) {
      return Api.query(category, options);
    }

    const options = { pageSize, page: apiPage, orderings };
    fetchApi(options).then((response) => {
      if (response?.length > 0) {
        if (blogPosts.length !== 0) {
          setBlogPosts([...blogPosts, response]);
        } else {
          setBlogPosts(response);
        }
      } else {
        setShouldFetchMoreBlogs(false);
      }
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [apiPage]);

  async function handleSeeMoreClick() {
    setApiPage(apiPage + 1);
  }

  function renderBlogPosts() {
    if (blogPosts.length > 0) {
      return blogPosts.map((blog, index) => (
        <Link to={{ pathname: `/blog/${blog.uid}`, ...blog }} key={index}>
          <BlogPreview key={index} {...blog} />
        </Link>
      ));
    }
  }

  function renderSeeMoreButton() {
    debugger;
    if (blogPosts.length > 0) {
      if (blogPosts?.length % 12 === 0 && shouldFetchMoreBlogs) {
        return (
          <div className="see-more-container">
            <button className="see-more-button" onClick={handleSeeMoreClick}>
              Veja Mais
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className="content blog">
      <h1>BLOG</h1>
      <div className="blog-posts">{renderBlogPosts()}</div>
      {renderSeeMoreButton()}
    </section>
  );
}

export default Blog;
```

It fails 'cause it only finds the initial 12 blog posts, even though it shows that the api was called twice.
There's obviously some async issue here.

I've tried switching from fireEvent to userEvent, from waitFor to find*, but it still doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Can't help without seeing the code of the component

Comment: @slideshowp2 Fair enough. Just updated it.

Comment: Does your logic even work outside the tests? You're mutating the `blogPosts` state variable inside `handleSeeMoreClick`.  You should do `const blogPostsList = [...blogPosts];` when you declare `blogPostsList`.

Comment: Yes it does @juliomalves ```t works as expected on the browser but when I simulate the behavior on react testing library it doesn't.```

Comment: TBH @juliomalves, the code I have right now is using the spread operator way of updating the state, but that doesn't affect anything on it. I'll update the sample code here.